# Javascript - strikethrough

Tags: javascript

i try to make text strikethrough with javascript.
I know nothing about Javascript and try to search on the net how to that.

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
            function recal(val,sum)
            { 
                if(sum == true)
                {
                    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML, 10);
                    total+=val;
                    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=total;        
                }
                else
                {
                    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("total").innerHTML, 10);
                    total-=val;
                    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=total;   
                    var pnl = document.getElementById("totalEvents");
                }



                var pnl = document.getElementById("totalEvents");
                var pnl2 = document.getElementById("eventCategory");
                var pnl3 = document.getElementById("nameID");

                **strikethrough starts here**
                if (!sum && pnl.firstChild.tagName != "S" && pnl2.firstChild.tagname !="S")
                {
                    pnl.innerHTML = "<S>"+ pnl.innerHTML+"</S>";
                    pnl2.innerHTML = "<S>"+ pnl2.innerHTML+"</S>";
                }
                else 
                {
                    pnl.innerHTML = pnl.firstChild.innerHTML;
                    pnl2.innerHTML = pnl2.firstChild.innerHTML;
                }



            }
        </script>
```

it makes textstrikethrough but something is wrong. Even if i choose second checkbox it affects first checkbox why :(

http://jsfiddle.net/aHH9w/ (my full  html page)

[image]

[image]

Comment: how you organized the markup? Maybe it's possibile to achieve the same effect using css only (or less javascript)

Comment: Can you post your html and script on jsfiddle.net ? also what's with the firstchild? there are simpler and safer ways such as `object.getElementsBytagName("s").length>0`

Comment: With JS Fiddle: put the rendered/output html into the html panel, the css into the css panel and the JavaScript into the JavaScript panel. You only need the contents enclosed within the `body` tag for the HTML.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are peforming a pretty convoluted way of achieving this, something that can actually be quite easily done. If you have an HTML element, say with the id 'myelement':

```
<div id="myelement">Hello world</div>
```

To create a strikethrough, all you need to do in JS is:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("myelement");
ele.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
```

If you need to check if there is a strikethrough on an element:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("myelement");
var isStruck = (ele.style.getProperty("text-decoration") == "line-through");
```

Although this is not really recommended. Use an internal variable to keep track of state.

Comment: how can i change to normal if its is strike?

Comment: however, there is still a problem because when i choose second one to strike first is strike

Comment: to change it to normal, simply do this: ele.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "none");

Comment: what the wrong is that when i click to second one it affects first one why :S

Comment: Because irrespective of what you click, the only two elements you are looking for elements with the id 'totalEvents' and 'eventCategory', which is probably the two in the first line. You need to generate ids such that they are unique for each row, or implement a logic to get an array of them. Either ways, there is a lot of reengineering involved here. I suggest you pick up a book on JavaScript first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8013/discussion-between-mert-metn-and-rohan-prabhu)

Comment: Isn't it getPropertyValue instead?